# what kind of scheduler does FreeRTOS use?

Tags: rtos, freertos

What kind of scheduler does FreeRTOS Use?

I have read somewhere that it is a run to complete scheduler, but on the other hand, I've also seen it being used with parallel tasks, so it wouldn't be a round robin scheduler?

Comment: A question most easily answered by the products own [documentation](http://www.freertos.org/implementation/a00002.html).  It supports pre-emptive, co-operative and round-robin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The highest priority task is granted CPU time. If multiple tasks have equal priority, it uses round-robin scheduling among them. Lower priority tasks must wait.

It is important that high priority tasks don't execute 100% of the time, because lower priority tasks would never get CPU time. It's a fundamental problem of real-time programming.

Usually, you want to assign a high priority to a task that must react fast to some important event, perform quick action, and go to sleep, letting less important stuff to work in the meantime.

A generic example of such a system may be:

1. highest priority - device drivers tasks (valve control, ADC, DAC, etc)
2. medium priority - administrative subsystem (console task, telnet task)
3. lower priority - several application tasks (www server, data processing, etc)

Lowest priority is given to general applications, that are scheduled using round-robin, which gives a more or less equal number of CPU time.

Medium priority - console tasks. The system operator cannot be cut off by a malfunctioning www server that gets stuck in an infinite loop. Those tasks are not running 100% of the time. For example, it may execute command-line commands from the administrator.

Highest priority - device drivers, handling critical events, such as machinery control. You may be interested in opening a safety valve if boiler pressure gets too high and you really don't want to wait until some stupid HTML rendering is finished in the webserver thread. Such tasks are run for a limited amount of time only.